Font shape '...'in size <16> not available - changes to do in Springer Nature template
I am getting font errors especially with Springer Nature Template. The font shapes 'OT1/cmr/m/n', 'OML/cmm/m/it', 'OMS/cmsy/m/n' and 'U/rsfs/m/n' are shown not available in the template. I have used a Springer Nature template before, this is the first time I am facing this issue. I added packages such as 'anyfontsize', '[T1] fontenc' and 'lmodern', but unable to make the errors go away. These errors appear with pdflatex or xelatex, any other causes compile time-out. The log box looks as follows:

Are there any changes I can do in the class file/ tex file or add any separate packages?

probably putting \RequirePackage{fix-cm} as the first line (before \documentclass  will fix this (at least the cm ones, not rsfs)

Thanks...this solved the issue of OT1, OML and OMS fonts. What to do about U/rsfs? It is still there even after adding fix-cm.

You could just ignore it or add after loading rsfs,  \DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{ <-7> rsfs5    <7-8> rsfs7    <8-> rsfs10 }{}

Even if I add this command, nothing changes. I have to submit this paper, so there should not be any errors or warnings. Can I suppress this one without correcting?

it's only a warning and unless you really have massive 16pt high script letters the warning has no effect on the output so you can safely ignore.

Thank you so much @DavidCarlisle! I submitted my manuscript with PDF well-generated.
